# iphone app UI design for add to favorites?

Tags: iphone, user-interface

After the right '+' button is pressed the item in that view is added to favorites and an UIAlertView is shown on screen saying "Added to Favorites". After it is added to favorites I make the '+' button disappear so the same item doesn't get added again to favorites. I am not sure if this ok with Apple's Human Interface Guidelines instead should the '+' remain there and if pressed again say "This item is already in favorites"?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: If you have a way to remove the item from favourites and make the button reappear again, then I think this is fine. If not you could just try setting `button.enabled = NO` instead?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the AlertView for this. By showing the alert, you force the user to confirm reading some confirmation message and taking action (by pressing the OK button). It is a good idea to provide feedback that the favorite was successfully added, but this should not be an intrusive alert. Perhaps you can use other design patterns for favorites, such as a star that lights up when pressed to indicate that the item is listed as a favorite, or perhaps an animation effect that 'moves' the selected item to a visible 'favorites' category.

The Human Interface Guidelines have [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH13-SW8) to say about the Alert view (in relation to your question):

> **Avoid creating unnecessary alerts.**
>
> These alerts are usually unnecessary
>   if they:
>
> - Merely increase the visibility of some
>     information, especially information
>     that is related to the standard
>     functioning of your application.
>     Instead, you should design an
>     eye-catching way to display the
>     information that harmonizes with your
>     app’s style.

Comment: As a supplement to Daan's answer, I recommend you use this, MBProgressHUD, as a way to display the info, https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD .

Answer (score 0):

Why not have two states for the button ? A "selected" state (for example negative contrast) showing the item is in favorites, and a "normal" state indicating it can be taped.

This way you can add/remove from favorite using the same button, and in a less obstructive way than with a `UIAlertView`.

I also suggest you use a ★ instead of a +